# Row/Column ordering/editing. How can I delete divs only for a certain breakpoint?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

[image: this is what I need :)]

As you can see in the attached image, in desktop version I have 8 divs in 2 rows and 4 columns, but in mobile version I need to have only 6 of those divs (not showing 2 of them) organized in 3 rows and 2 columns. Please take a look at the picture so you can understand the order I need.

Any ideas on how can I achieve this?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry to say that if you don't know where to start on this, you're probably in over your head. CSS is designed to manipulate the layout/design of the page, not to manipulate the content. You'll need to use JS (JavaScript), or make your backend scripts aware of whether they are serving the content to mobile. If that's not something that's obvious to you today, then you've got a lot of learning to do before you can implement a good solution.

Comment: @thelr You can implement it easily using media queries and `flex` or `grid` with pure css (No js is required). OP should create a [mcve] of what he tried

Comment: @thelr Content is also part of the layout/design of the page. And I found a way of doing this with **flex** and **display: none;** for the divs I want to hide in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my question because I found a way to do what I wanted. And this is it:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.item {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .item {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .item-invisible {
    display: none;
  }
}
.item-content {
  background-color: #999;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-invisible">
    <div class="item-content">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">7</div>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-invisible">
    <div class="item-content">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks anyway :)